# Add RubberBand on Silverlight Image Control

Tags: silverlight

I want to have a rubberband on a silverlight image control, in order to select zones on an image and copy it.

Thanks for your help.

(No specific version of SL required)

Guys??? Where are the experts? any ideas? remarks, anything....????

Comment: can you please be more specific? What is a "rubber band" in your own words? What have you tried?

Comment: A Rubber Band is a selection rectangle that you draw on an image with the mouse.
With this rectangle, i can select a zone of an image and say copy it or rotate or....

Comment: start with mouse events, click and drag the mouse creating a rectangle whos width, height, x and y all correspond to the place that you are dragging to. Then look into the graphics classes in WPF, these allow you to get the bytes of an image, since you will have the x,y, width and height of your rectangle, you can 'get' the bytes (i.e. pixels) of your selected area, then save that image to either the file system or create another Image control out of it.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to add a rubber band is to create a dynamic rectangle on your image control when a mouse click occurs such as:

```
private void cMain_MouseLeftButtonDown( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e )
{
    OriginatingPostionOnCanvas = e.GetPosition( cMain );

    RubberBandBox = new Rectangle() { Width = 1, 
                                        Height = 1, 
                                        Fill = new SolidColorBrush( Colors.Red ), 
                                        Opacity = .1 };

    RubberBandBox.SetValue( Canvas.LeftProperty, OriginatingPostionOnCanvas.X);
    RubberBandBox.SetValue( Canvas.TopProperty,  OriginatingPostionOnCanvas.Y );

    cMain.Children.Add( RubberBandBox );
}
```

Then one handles the mouse movements and resizes the rectangle as appropriate. I provide more detail about a process with a canvas on my blog entitled [Silverlight (How To): Manipulation of Dynamic Selection Rubber Band in C#](http://omegacoder.com/?p=897)